# Wait for save file dialog in firefox

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

I need wait for save file dialog in firefox in my automated test. It's not element of the page. How can I do this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fjr8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is tool to Automate Web Application. The file download dialog is a native component and so you can't do any action on it. And so you can't wait for that dialog.

I am not sure what you want to do with that dialog, may be you want to dialog a file. if that is the case you can configure your Firefox profile to automatic download the file to some specific directory when you click a link. or you can use **AutoIT** tool to write scrip which interact with this dialog and you can call this script from your selenium script.

Comment: you are right, thank you. I used AutoIt in a way you discribed, but I have a llitle other situation. May be the one way is to use sleep() in this situation.